# What chromium web browsers look almost exactly like regular chrome?

Tags: chrome, web-browser

**What chromium based browsers look and feel closest to regular chrome? And can use almost the most of chrome's extensions compared to others? Aside from citrio torch and chromodo**

I'm using windows 8.1 so I can't use edge.

--Also, there are websites for some of my college classes that require certificates. When I open those websites with internet explorer or vivaldi, I am asked for a certificate. However, on regular chrome, I am not asked for the certificate everytime. *I would like a browser that **Does Not** ask me for my certificate every single time like chrome*

> Why I'm asking:
>
> I use different browsers for different purposes
>
> - Firefox's homepage is wolfram alpha
>
>   - Chrome's homepage is school related
>   - Torch's homepage is youtube and is for media
>   - citrio web browser is for something else, chromodo for something else
>
> It may seem a bit excessive to install an entire new browser but hey I like being able to click a different button on the start bar for a different type of task. I might leave some work on in chrome then go to torch browser to listen to music on youtube. When I want to go back to work, I know exactly which windows to close.

Comment: Ever thought about [importing those certificates into the browser's "trusted store"](http://blogmines.com/blog/how-to-import-a-certificate-in-google-chrome/), so it 'never* asks you again to accept them? Having that issue ruled out, it looks to me as if your question hasn't much substance left – as the only requirement then would be "looks and feels like Chrome" and the best match for that would be "Chrome". What's wrong with it then – and does your question even stand then?

Comment: I explain above why I like using multiple different web browsers that look like chrome. Anyone who has tried a bunch of different chromium browsers, please respond.